# Define end of line and remove double quotes when concatenating files

Tags: powershell

I need to concatenate multiple text files (skipping the headers) into one big file using PowerShell. Currently I'm using this command:

```
Get-Content *.txt |
    Select-String -Pattern "^[1-9]" |
    Select-Object line |
    Export-Csv mybigfile.txt
```

I now have two issues:

- How to define the end of line? It will automatically use `CRLF` and I need only `LF` like in the source files.
- How to remove double quotes? It will automatically add double quotes around each line and around columns that are already double quoted in the source files.

**Example:**

Source input:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4
3145,"blabla",4568,""LF
```

Current output:

```
"3145,""blabla"",4568,""""CRLF
```

Desired output:

```
3145,"blabla",4568,""LF
```

Comment: Can you provide two sample records, the actual output and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell cmdlets use the system's default line terminator (CR-LF), so they can't do what you want. Use a [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader 'C:\path\to\input.txt'
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ('C:\path\to\output.txt', $true)

# override default line terminator
$writer.NewLine = "`n"

# skip first line of input file
if ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
  $reader.ReadLine() | Out-Null
}

while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
  $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
}

$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: A little bit more complex than I thought but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet with the `-Filter` parameter to retrieve all text files, load the content using [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) and skip the first line using the [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) cmdlet and the `-skip` parameter.

You then have a string array which you can join together by `LF` and finally write the file using the [Out-File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113363) cmdlet:

```
$output = Get-ChildItem 'your_path_here' -Filter '*.txt' | Foreach { $_ | Get-Content | Select -Skip 1 }
$output -join "`n" | out-file 'mybigfile.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is almost working. The last line is still ended by a CRLF instead of LF.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try the `Set-Content` cmdlet instead of `Out-File`

Comment: Either of them appends CR-LF to the output.